# How to store a range as a field in a class?

Tags: c++, range-v3

I would like to store a range as a field in a class, so that I could reuse it several times later on. However, unlike local variables, I cannot simply specify it type as `auto`. On the other hand, the types of ranges that the library creates are very complex. It would take me disproportionately long time to figure out the correct type by hand + it would be unmaintainable in the future if I would choose to change how the range is obtained.

So, I thought, maybe I could use `decltype` to help myself:

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    using MyRange = decltype(std::declval<std::vector<int*>>() | ranges::v3::view::filter([=](int* elem) { return true; }));
    MyRange range;
}
```

(note: my actual `std::declval` is actually more complex, but I wanted to make the example brief.)

But I get an error:
`a lambda cannot appear in an unevaluated context`

So, my question is:

- How can I avoid using the lambda and get my `decltype` working?
- Or maybe there is a better/cleaner way to get a type of a range in order to declare it as a field in a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language is being helpful here: if the lambda were allowed in `decltype`, it wouldn't help you, because there would be no way for you to produce a value of type `MyRange` other than via default-initialization. Since very occurrence of a lambda expression has a unique type, you couldn't produce a function object of the correct type to pass to `view::filter` to get it to return something you could store in a `MyRange`.

The workaround is to "don't do that"; e.g., store your function object somewhere and refer to it in the `decltype`. In C++17, [for example](https://godbolt.org/z/v8WK8a):

```
struct MyClass {
    static constexpr auto pred = [](int* elem) { return true; };
    using MyRange = decltype(std::declval<std::vector<int*>&>() | ranges::v3::view::filter(pred));
    MyRange range;
};
```

Note the use of `std::vector&`. This is required as explained in [Explicit range-v3 decltype evaluates to void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664253/explicit-range-v3-decltype-evaluates-to-void)