# Explicit range-v3 decltype evaluates to void?

Tags: c++, c++17, range-v3

I am trying to get an explicit type of a range (I may want to store it as a field in a class in the future). However, for some reason, it evaluates to `void`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

class Alpha {
public:
  int x;
};

class Beta : public Alpha {

};

class Foo {
public:
  std::set<Alpha*> s;

  using RangeReturn = decltype(std::declval<std::set<Alpha*>>() | ranges::v3::view::transform(std::function<Beta*(Alpha*)>()));
  RangeReturn r();
};

Foo::RangeReturn Foo::r() {
  return s | ranges::v3::view::transform([](Alpha* a) { return static_cast<Beta*>(a); });
}

int main() {
}
```

When compiling with g++ -std=c++17, it gives

```
main.cpp:24:88: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
```

(g++ version g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0)

I get an error of similar kind on Visual Studio 2017, v. 15.9

---

This question is a continuation of my other question: [How to store a range as a field in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546616/how-to-store-a-range-as-a-field-in-a-class) but is more specific and I believe it deserves to be separate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because:

- range/v3 view disables view from rvalue, because that will cause dangling reference. Thus in your `declval()`, you should also use an lvalue:

  ```
  std::declval<std::set<Alpha*>&>()
  //                           ^ here should be lvalue
  ```
- view transformation information is encoded inside the template parameter. So if you use `view::transform(std::function<Beta*(Alpha*)>())` to represent the type, your expression should have exactly the same type. A lambda is not ok.

A working version would be:

```
class Foo {
public:
  std::set<Alpha*> s;

  using RangeReturn = decltype(std::declval<std::set<Alpha*>&>() | ranges::v3::view::transform(std::function<Beta*(Alpha*)>()));
  RangeReturn r();
};

Foo::RangeReturn Foo::r() {
  return s | ranges::v3::view::transform(std::function<Beta*(Alpha*)>{
          [](Alpha* a) { return static_cast<Beta*>(a); }
          });
}
```

But actually, it's not a good idea to store a view this way.

Comment: @CygnusX1 It might be opinion based. The type of a view is an implementation detail that its user should not care about. I don't know why you want to store that type, I would use `auto` as return type and let the compiler to deduce.

Comment: Ironically, I need the type for the exactly same reason. The function body is an implementation detail and I want to move it to cpp file. But that leaves the return type at the declaration site without anything to deduct from, so it cannot be auto.