# How to hide the complex range type of a range-v3?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, range-v3

I need a class with a method that returns some kind of range using the range-v3 library.
In order to implement such a class I can write it everything right in the definition of that class. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

class Alpha {
public:
  int x;
};

class Beta : public Alpha {};

class Foo {
public:
  std::set<Alpha*> s;

  auto r() { return s | ranges::v3::view::transform([](Alpha* a) { return static_cast<Beta*>(a); }) }
};
```

However, in my real case the `Foo::r` function is quite complex and I would like to hide its implementation.
In particular, the implementation make uses of some additional libraries that otherwise do not need to be included when the class `Foo` is declared.

However, when the definition of `Foo::r` is separated from its declaration, its return type must be specified explicitly. [`decltype` comes with some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664253/explicit-range-v3-decltype-evaluates-to-void):

Header file(s):

```
class Foo {
public:
  std::set<Alpha*> s;

  using RangeReturn = decltype(std::declval<std::set<Alpha*>&>() | ranges::v3::view::transform(std::function<Beta*(Alpha*)>()));
  RangeReturn r();
};
```

Implementation, cpp file:

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::RangeReturn Foo::r() {
    return s | ranges::v3::view::transform(std::function<Beta*(Alpha*)>{
      [](Alpha* a) { return static_cast<Beta*>(a); }
      });
}
```

This does the immediate job of hiding the actual implementation of `Foo::r`.
However, the type of the return value still effectively "leaks" the information on how the range is constructed.
What is probably worse, I am now forced to explicitly use an `std::function` object in the range pipeline.

But is that all information really needed by the user of the returned range? All the user of `Foo::r` cares is that it is some kind of iterable. It has:

- `begin()` giving an iterator to the beginning of the range
- `end()` giving some iterator or sentinel
- Iterator can be incremented, to iterate over the range
- Iterator can be dereferenced, giving some type `T` (`Beta*` in the example case).

The user does not care that there is a transform view or not, nor the number of transformations, filters and whatnot.

So, **my question is** -- is there a way to hide all that information? I would like to be able to write something like this:

In the header:

```
class Foo {
public:
  std::set<Alpha*> s;

  Iterable<Beta*> r();
};
```

In the cpp file:

```
#include "Foo.h"

Iterable<Beta*> Foo::r() {
    return s | ranges::v3::view::transform([](Alpha* a) { return static_cast<Beta*>(a); });
}
```

I can accept the fact that the produced `Iterable` type may contain real function calls that cannot be inlined due to the hiding process.
A link-time optimisation may or may not be able to optimise it later.

Unfortunately, to my knowledge, such `Iterable` is merely a concept and not a separate type in the library.

Comment: From documentation of Range-v3: _`any_view<T>(rng)` - Type-erased range of elements with value type T; can store any range with this value type._ Wouldn't that help? (I haven't seen it before, just googled it for "range-v3 type erasure" :).

Comment: Looks to me like a case for type-erasure.

Comment: Without type erasure, you won't have a good way to spell out the return type. Same as if you had a function returning a lambda - you either type-erase the return type (std::function) or the definition must be in the header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `r()` you are looking for is `ranges::v3::any_view<Beta*>`.

Note that it applies type erasure that implies some runtime performance penalty which might be significant. Relevant discussion: [poor performance of type-erased views](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/714).

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JylKIHD0NaQsRXdB

Comment: I wanted to comment that it fails to compile.... until I realized that `any_view` is not in a `ranges::v3::view` namespace, but directly under `ranges::v3`!